# Read QR from IOS Devices

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need a plugin to read QR codes.
I have tried using Instascan and it works fine, but it doesn't work on iOS devices.

If anyone knows any plugin that works on iOS devices, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I recommend using Ionic Framework. Might be very overkill for a feature such as QR scanner but if you do have other features too, this will be a good choice.

Comment: I have many features also my app build on AngualrJS

Comment: Ionic v1 is based on AngularJS. Don't worry.

Comment: the problem QR is just a small part I have a whole CRM project

Answer (score 0):

Instascan works on iOS if you add `autoplay playsinline controls` to your video element.

```
<video class="embed-responsive-item" autoplay playsinline controls  id="preview"></video>
```